# drupal jquery error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I'm trying to use `jquery` in `Drupal 7`. I have put the following code in a module `js` file, and loaded it with `drupal_add_js`. At first this same error occurred in my module `js` file and after googling I found that I should wrap the code in a function. But after fixing that, the error occurred in `jquery.js?v=1.4.4`. Here's my code:

```
(function($) {
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("div#top-bar-menu-wrapper");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
}(jQuery));
```

and an screenshot of the error:

[image: Uncaught type error screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
container.is(e.target)
```

`jQuery.is()` has taken an *element* as parameter. This is ok in jQuery 1.6<= but Drupals7's default jQuery is 1.4.4.

So a jquery update solved my problem.